# YAML Pipeline Scan python

Tags: python, yaml, click

I have to write a python script where I need to parse YAML file and produce the list of steps that includes the image version for example:
this is the step

```
Step 1:
  stage: setup
  description: 
  title: Check plugin
  fail_fast: false
  *image: 'Image-Name'*
  commands:
    - apt update
```

Fetch the images version under the particular stage and lists all steps and the version of the image used by each step.
Output should be in list

```
Step 1:
   robot_image:1.0.1
```

Data is in Variable and its showing as string type and now need to filter it base on the Step and print the image with step

```
unit_test:
    stage: build
    fail_fast: false
    title: Generate test results report
    type: freestyle
    image: 'docker-test-reporting.1.0'
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: where does the `1.0.1` come from, c.q. why is this not `1.0.0`  or `1.1.1` ?

Comment: 1.0.1 is a example version it should be anything Base on the image in yaml

Comment: When we fetch the data from api and store it into variable, variable type is showing <String>, How can i Filter it